# Prevent escaping of slashes in reverse routes

Tags: java, escaping, routes, playframework

In my Play app when I use reverse routing to generate links, forward slashes in parameters are being escaped, and I'd rather they weren't.

For example:

```
<a href="@{Application.page('about/contact')}">Contact Us</a>
```

generates a working link, but takes you to `/about%2Fcontact.html` rather than `/about/contact.html`. (Entering `/about/contact.html` in the address bar also goes to the right place.)

I'm doing this because I've only got a few pages that do anything interesting and the rest are basically static -- they only use the basic template features (`extends`,`include`,`get`,`set`). Since creating separate controllers and actions for each of them would be overkill I've set up a single action to handle all of them.

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    public static void page(String path) {
        render("/static/" + path + ".html");
    }
}
```

handled with one route:

```
GET     /{<.+>path}.html                Application.page
```

Any idea how I can change things around so that the slashes aren't encoded?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand but why don't you just put the link to the static page in the <a href="/static/contact.html">XXX</a> ?

Comment: I have tried looking at the source code for how the RouteArgs are configured, but I don't see any way this can be overridden, unless you change the source of Play and change it for all reverse routing.

Answer (score 1):

Since we (apparently) can't override the way RouteArgs works, we can decode the given url in the method, like this :

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    public static void page(String path) {
        render("/static/" + URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8"); + ".html");
    }
}
```

But be aware of security risks! (well, .html not so much, but just in case ...)